Yandex map api данные для clusterIconLayout
const init = () => {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [41.651107, 41.636269],
    zoom: 13,
    controls: ['zoomControl']
  })

  clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
    clusterIconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
      `<div class="map__object"><div class="map__object-content"><div class="map__object-quantity">{{properties.geoObjects.length}}</div></div></div>`
    ),
    groupByCoordinates: true,
    openHintOnHover: false,
    clusterIconShape: {
      type: 'Circle',
      coordinates: [0, -16],
      radius: 24
    }
  })

}

const updateMapMarkers = () => {


  array.forEach((item) => {
    const coords = [item.coords.lat, item.coords.lng]

    
    const placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
      coords,
      {
        iconContent: VALUE,
        customData: {
          id: item._id
        }
      },
      {
        iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
          `<div>$[properties.iconContent]</div>`
        ),
       
      }
    )
    clusterer.add(placemark)
  })

  myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer)
}

Как в каждом кластере clusterIconLayout получить массив данных геобъектов ({properties.iconContent} - VALUE), чтобы найти минимальное значение value и вывести его вместо {properties.geoObjects.length}

Для получения массива геообъектов, добавленных в кластеризатор, используйте функцию getGeoObjects(). Чтобы получить координаты объектов, вы можете использовать .geometry._coordinates для IGeoObject. Если необходимо получать другие свойства геообъектов в кластере, используйте аналогичные обращения к свойствам геообъектов.

Не понимаю
clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
clusterIconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
<div class="map__object"><div ><div >{{получить массив геобъектов, в которых есть customData.price. Вывести мин. значение}}</div></div></div>
),
})
